# How can I minimize possible future ties to economics and live as stress-free as possible on an economic level?

Tags: united-states, banking, debt-reduction

I have no other way to phrase this but for some reason, even the meer mention of most personal finance topics sets off panic attacks (probably a lack of understanding or ability to comprehend the subject, I'm terrible at math, I don't know) so to prevent constant anxiety attacks and potential homelessness, I am going to live as low-money as possible.

How can I minimize possible future ties to economics and live as stress-free as possible on an economic level?

Comment: Get a cabin in the woods and farm/hunt/gather your own food? Hopefully noone will come after you for property taxes...

Comment: @littleadv that's the current plan

Comment: I am being fully serious

Comment: You’re SOL.  Even a hermit living in a cabin in the woods needs salt, ammunition, gunpowder, etc.  And how are you going to buy the land and get the supplies to build the cabin?  Do you even know how to build a cabin?

Comment: 1. The goal is minimizing, no banks, no investing, just what I make, so I'll buy stuff, I'm still working. 
2. kinda

Comment: It isn't possible. We are all forced to live in this economic system (capitalism).

Comment: You don't *have* to understand most personal finance topics. If you can handle a bank account and a budget, that's 90% of it. If you don't insist on fighting with it, investment is straightforward; just talk to an advisor about your risk tolerances and have them recommend a tested mix of low-fee index funds, then mostly ignore them except for putting more money into them periodically and rebalancing maybe once a year. Taxes are usually not a tremendous hassle if you don't insist on fighting with them either. There are classes which can help you learn the basics

Comment: The actual question is not in a form that's really on topic here, or answerable as more than opinion. If you had a more specific problem you were trying to overcome we might be able to help. As phrased, it's too fuzzy, hard to pin down hood brief answers for, and those answers would mostly not be personal finance answers. I think you're better off finding a community specifically focused on that topic.

Comment: Seek help from a mental health professional, trying to live outside of society is not a reasonable response, addressing the anxiety is.

Comment: @RonJohn should we be concerned why your first thoughts about the requirements for off-grid living were ammunition and  gunpowder?

Comment: @user253751 why should you be, when hunting with a gun is a hell of a lot easier than hunting not-with-a-gun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personal finance is nothing more than simple addition and subtraction: add up all of the incoming money, and subtract all of the outgoing money.

Things are good if the final number is greater than zero at the end of their month, and bad if the number is less than zero.

You also aren’t the first — or 80,000th — person to want to deny or hide from money problems.

But you can’t.  Eventually you’ve got to face reality.

EDIT: the *real* issues are organization and discipline.  Fortunately, computers and the internet help with that (though they also make it easier to excessively spend).